# Database Design for UserName SAAS website

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database-design, saas

This may have been answered, I looked but honestly don't know what I should search on.  because everything I search on isn't what i want.

Anyway, I am building a ASP.NET SAAS project.

This is my delima, multiple companies will be using the software.   I am building it so they themselves can manage their user base.

This is all in one SQL Server DB.

Right now the way it is designed I have a user table that has userid (identity), username, password, companyfk, first name, last name, email.  the primary key is userid.  The secondary Primary key I say is username.

When someone enters in a user with a particular username it will search to see if that username is taken in the entire table (not based off company).

This could be a problem, I see of people trying to find usernames that work and are professional sounding for the organization.

Couple of options

1. Do I, have the system make the username itself and give it to them?
2. Do I partially make the user name and allow them to do the rest.  Here I could assign each company a 3 letter abbrev and append it to the user name.
3. Do I make the username search also be specific only for that company.  here the problem I see is when they attempt to login how will I know what company will be logging in.  I don't think it is wise to advertise a drop down list of all the companies using the system on the log in page.
4. Do I make a helper tool like yahoo does that as they are typing it tells them if it is 
   taken and does a suggestion?  This is the more difficult of the 5 choices.
5. Do I just keep it the way it is and let them deal with the headache (easiest choice of all)

I am leaning towards option (2).

And I am wondering if anyone has thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, the easiest way to solve the issue is for them to supply their email address and make that their username.

Considering no two email addresses are the same, I'd say you'd have it made.

Comment: Justin, that was something I honestly didn't think of.  Duh.. That was pretty obvious.  Thanks!

Comment: After thinking about this.  The only obstacle to this is the ability to test.  The sites has permissions so qa staff needs to have the ability to have multiple accounts to test various roles through automated test procedures that are set up.  We would have to set up multiple emails accounts for those tests that have email receiving functionality needed for the different roles.

Comment: @Angela - Why would you need that? Each login should be able to have more than one role. You should be able to do all of the tests with a single email address that has all of the roles you need.

Comment: Justin, several reasons.  One being organizational hierarchy, Manager versus non manager roles.  For instance in one case one role has the ability to approve something and another role doesn't have the ability to approve something. Simple case of a button being enabled for that action on the *same* page for when it is a manager and that button is disabled when it is a non-manager person.

If a user has both Manager & Non Manager roles. Which role to follow? How would you test both?  You can't. the button can't be enabled and disabled at the same time.  Thus automation wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Justin on using email address as it’s the most obvious unique field.

If you really want to go with the username I’d consider requiring company ID as additional field when logging in. This was you can have two identical user names in the table but not in the company.

Comment: Thanks George for the thought... I will keep that in mind.  but I think Justin is correct that is the simplest for the user.  Might make a little more work on the back end for the QA process but I am sure a work around can be used.